# Spring Required List parameter 'tagArray[]' is not present

Tags: java, arrays, spring, jsp, set

A beginner spring guy's here. I need to pass data from spring jsp form to controller. The problem is that one of my object's property is Set and I have to pass array data to controller. I did it using jQuery.

Fragment of jsp' code with form:

```
<form:form action="savePost" method="post" commandName="blogpost">
                <tr><td>Title: </td> <td><form:input path="title"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Content: </td> <td><form:input path="content"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Author: </td> <td><form:input path="author"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Tags: </td> <td><form:input path="tags" id="tags"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Blog post save"></td></tr>
            </form:form>
```

and my bean's code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="posts")
public class BlogPost {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="post_title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name="post_content")
    private String content;

    @Column(name="post_author", nullable = false)
    private String author;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "blogPost")
    private List<Comment> comments;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="BLOGPOST_TAG",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "POST_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name= "TAG_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private Set<Tag> tags;

    public BlogPost(){}

    public BlogPost(String title, String content, String author) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public BlogPost(String title, String content, String author, Set<Tag> tags) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
        this.author = author;
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public BlogPost(long id, String title, String content, String author, Set<Tag> tags) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
        this.author = author;
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public List<Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(List<Comment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "ID: "+getId()+", title: "+getTitle()+", content: "+getContent()+", author: "+getAuthor()+"\n";
    }

    public Set<Tag> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(Set<Tag> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }
}
```

second one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tags")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="tag_content")
    private String content;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    private List<BlogPost> blogposts;

    public Tag(){}

    public Tag(String content){
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Tag(long id, String content) {this.id = id; this.content = content; }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }


    public List<BlogPost> getBlogposts() {
        return blogposts;
    }

    public void setBlogposts(List<BlogPost> blogposts) {
        this.blogposts = blogposts;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Controler's code:

```
@PostMapping(value = {"savePost","/updatePost"})
public String createOrUpdatePostPOST (@Valid @ModelAttribute("blogpost") BlogPost blogpost,
                                      BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request, Model model,
                                      @RequestParam(value="tagArray[]") List<String> myArray){

    //Loop to show data from jsp
    for (String tag : myArray){
        System.out.println(tag);

    }

    String mappingValue = request.getServletPath();

    blogPostValidator.validate(blogpost, bindingResult);

    List<BlogPost> listOfBlogPostsToGetLastindex = repo.findFirstByOrderByIdDesc();

    long newCommentId = listOfBlogPostsToGetLastindex.get(0).getId()+1;

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

        if (mappingValue.contains("/savePost")){
            model.addAttribute("status", 0);

            return EDIT_PAGE_VIEW;
        }

        else {
            model.addAttribute("status", 2);

            return EDIT_PAGE_VIEW;
        }
    }

    else{

        blogpost.setId(newCommentId);
        repo.save(utilityService.returnCapitalizedPostObject(blogpost));

        return "redirect:/create-or-update-success";
    }
}
```

The problem now is that although I can see passed data using `System.out`, I get error `Required List parameter 'tagArray[]' is not present`. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: show your controller code

Comment: I updated my code.

Comment: Ok, the problem solved. The best solution is: Just walk away from keyboard, relax for 5 minutes and go back with fresh mind :) One thing that was missing was name="tagArray" for tag input. Now everything is already working just fine.